# Do you have to leave something behind to go forward? (ie a contained system)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, propulsion

By "behind" I mean a particle outside of the box.

( assume a 1d system)Imagine a closed box. And at the very center of that box, is a device that fires particles 1,2 in opposite direction.

**Scenario 1:**

At the start

$P_{box} = 0$

$P_{1} = 0$

$P_{2} = 0$

Now the particles are fired, such that at t = 0

$P_{box}= 0$

$P_{1} = -mv$

$P_{2} = mv$

The net momentum is zero so nothing is violated.

Each particle moves the same distance, and strikes the wall of the box at the same time. Assuming all have elastic collisions. The net momentum now is:

$P_{box}= (-mv) + (mv) = 0$

$P_{1} = 0$

$P_{2} = 0$

Which is what we expect, they collide at the SAME time, and then strike the box, causing no net movement of the box.

**Scenario 2:**

Now instead of the device that fires the particles being at the center, let the device Touch the left wall.

When t=0

$P_{box}= 0$

$P_{1} = -mv$

$P_{2} = mv$

Which is the same as before,

However, as soon as time "starts", the particle 1, hits the left side of the wall before particle 2 hits the right. Once this happens it elastically transfers its momentum.

As soon as this first collision happens

$P_{box}= -mv$

$P_{1} = 0$

$P_{2} = mv$

The box as a result of the collision is now moving left with a velocity of $-\frac{mv}{m_b}$, whilst particle 1 is now stationary at the coordinates x= 0

So as of now, there is definitely a way to move this box, what happens once time has elapsed and particle 2 hits the right wall? It transfers its momentum  elasticslly. Such that

$P_{box}= -mv + mv$

$P_{1} = 0$

$P_{2} = 0 $

After the second collision the box stops.

If everything up to now doesn't violate anything. Haven't we demonstrated it is atleast possible to move something  without leaving anything behind, atleast for a short while?

As soon as the first collision happens( which we assume happens instantaniously) ,

The box wall follows $x= -\frac{mv}{m_{b}}t + \frac{1}{2}l$

Where l is the length of the box.

the second particle follows  $x = vt - \frac{1}{2}l$

Calculating the collision time and finding the displacement of the box from its original position gives me

$$X=\frac{lm}{m_{b}+m}$$

So my question is: would this be considered a contraption that can move without leaving anything behind?

**Considerations:**

I have not considered the possibility of non elastic collisions,

I have not taken into account the delay between the first collision from the left side of the box,and the momentum transfered to the whole box.

I have not taken into account any radiation produced.

I have not considered moving a further distance by repeating this proccess.( as firing once leaves particles inside)

I have not provided a mechanism by which the particles are fired

I am very much aware this wouldn't be practical as you may aswell just use a rocket.

There is also a question of "let L be infinity" which is just basically a rocket. But that's not fun, and I think this a definition game on what we mean by "left behind"

Answer (score 3):

If the initial total momentum of the system is zero, then the position of the center of mass will stay constant no matter what, regardless of the elasticity of collisions. This means that if the box has moved in one direction, other things in the system must have moved in the opposite direction.

I don't understand how the collisions in your examples are elastic, or what elasticity has to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can move various parts of the closed system. There is no law against this. The only thing that is fixed is the center of mass of the system. Even for systems that you say that they leave things behind, if you consider the system including the things left behind, the center of mass does not move. If you consider a rocket in space, far from any star, and include the ejected gases in the system, the CoM does not move. By considering the convenient system, you can always make sure that "no something is left behind".